# How to unlock the bootloader on Verizon Galaxy S3 without phone service

Tags: bootloader-lock

How can I unlock the bootloader without any phone service? Do I have to take out the Verizon SIM to do this? The phone is already rooted and has the super user app. A website said it's possible to use [any] SIM card after unlocking. Is this true?

Comment: What's the ultimate goal you're trying to accomplish? You've made it sound like you want to use the phone on a different carrier, which brings up two important points: 1. Unlocking the bootloader is *not related* to the network (SIM) lock on a phone 2. Verizon phones only use SIM cards for 4G LTE data; you cannot use them on a different carrier, and you definitely can't use them on one that would require a SIM for voice coverage.

Comment: Is it not possible to take a Verizon phone to Sprint if it's network unlocked, @eldarerathis? I really don't know, I only know they both use CDMA for voice calls.

Comment: @TreborRude: Generally, no. From a technical standpoint they overlap in one voice frequency (1900 MHz), but both networks essentially keep a database of approved device ESNs. If your device isn't on the list (meaning, if it's not a device the carrier sells branded for their network) you typically won't be able to get it activated without "knowing a guy" or doing something of questionable legality. Even then it's usually unlikely; they want to keep you locked to their network. So from a practical standpoint, it's just not feasible.

Comment: Good to know, @eldarerathis. Is it the same with GSM carriers in the States? Most of my mobile phone experience is from England, where the state of mobile affairs seems to much simpler than it is here.

Comment: @TreborRude: GSM is pretty similar in the US, but most people simply don't buy unlocked devices like they do in other places (my understanding is that in Europe this is more the norm?). As long as the device supports the right bands and is unlocked, you can pop in a SIM and use it. The only real issue with unlocked GSM devices in the US is that the two biggest GSM carriers don't use the same 3G frequencies, although T-Mobile is gradually re-farming theirs to match AT&T's. You need a device that supports both 3G frequencies if you're not in a re-farmed area or you only get 2G/voice.

Comment: @eldarerathis as to the "norm" part: Yes, at least here in Germany non-simlocked phones seem to be the majority. I don't remember ever having had a locked one. But during the last years, I never bought a device from my carrier; only my first two devices came from them (which was more than 10 years ago). I also don't know a single person having a sim-locked device. So this seems very much a "localized issue" (oops -- OK, larger locality :)

Comment: I was given the phone because my friend went to another carrier. I under stand that carrier to carrier can;t be done

Comment: I understand carrier to carrier can't be done. it's after many hours reading on forums I would like to know if I wanted to use it, other than verizon exactly what are my options? any? The site I first went to [You tube] The author is phone rebel. said root and unlock verizon and Wah Lah! get the sims of your choice. From what you guys are saying this is BS!